# Network services abruptly stop working on win server 2k8

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share, troubleshooting

One of our windows servers has started acting up. All network services from roles on the server just stop working all of a sudden, untill the server is restarted. the issue occurs every other week or so. I can still access the server using VNC (remote desktop) and the server can reach network services on other servers in the network while the issue is active.

Symptoms:

- File shares don't show up when you browse for `//server-name`.
- Users are unable to print using the print service on the server.
- Users are unable to login via the server (gets logged in with temp profile).

I have tried troubleshooting this for a while, but with no success.

- It's not network related, our NMS can ping it at all times (and well, i can vnc to it when the issue is active, so there is that).
- It's not hardware related, NIC is fine and no HW resources are being used extensively.

Roles installed:

- AD/DC
- DHCP
- DNS
- File Services
- Print service
- Web Server (IIS)

No other applications are installed.
The server is located internationally so i can't just replace it.

Any help/ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Do you see any relevant entries in the server's event logs for the times in question? You will likely need to provide a lot more detail to get any helpful information here I suspect

Comment: Are the services in question stopped when the issue occurs or are they running but not responding?